# null pointer exception weighted graph

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, weighted

I'm trying to write a form a Dijkstra’s algorithm, with the weight between two vertices the distance between a set of coordinates taken in from a file. It adds the Vertices fine but when it goes to add in the edges I'm getting a null pointer in my main method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at matrix.matrix(matrix.java:61)
        at matrix.main(matrix.java:102)
```

Which point to the marked(**) parts of code. It's probably something really simple that I'm missing so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class matrix
{
    //public static double[][] distanceMatrix;
    public static int[] nameOfCities;
    public static double[] Latitude;
    public static double[] Longitude;
    public static Graph theGraph = new Graph();

    public static void matrix() 
    { 
        int size=0;

        try {
                File f = new File("Cities2.txt");//the file where the coordinates of cities are kept
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);

                int i=0;
                while(scan.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String readLine = scan.nextLine();
                    size++;
                }
                System.out.println("The number of cities is "+size);
                double[] Latitude = new double[size];
                double[] Longitude = new double[size];
                nameOfCities = new int[size];
                //double[][] distanceMatrix = new double[size][size];

                while(sc.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    String[] details = line.split(" ");//until there's a space(" ") in the file
                    int name = Integer.parseInt(details[0]);//number in the file corresponds to the name of the town
                    nameOfCities[i]=name;//add this to the array called nameOfCities
                        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(details[1]);//corresponds to latitude value
                    Latitude[i]=latitude;//add this to latitude array
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(details[2]);//corresponds to longitude array
                    Longitude[i]=longitude;//add this to longitude array

                    theGraph.addVertex(i+1);
                    theGraph.displayVertex(i);
                    System.out.println(" Vertex added");
                    i++;
                }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {         
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

        **for(int i=0; i<Latitude.length; i++)**
        {
            for(int j=i; j<Longitude.length; j++)
            {
                double distance = getDistance(Latitude[i],Longitude[i],Latitude[j],Longitude[j]);//gets distance between two points
                distance = (double)Math.round(distance*100000.0)/100000.0;
                //distanceMatrix[i][j] = distance;//inserts it into the matrix
                theGraph.addEdge(i,j,distance);
                System.out.print("Edge added.");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Distance matrix and graph filled.");//matrix is filled
    }

    public static double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        //gets the distance using haversine function
        double R = 6371;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians((lat2-lat1));
        double dLon = Math.toRadians((lon2-lon1)); 
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        double d = R * c;         
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Filling Graph...");
        **matrix();**
        System.out.print("Shortest paths: ");
        theGraph.path(); //shortest paths
        System.out.println();
    } // end main()
}
```

And here's my graph class

```
class Graph
{
    private final int MAX_VERTS = 80;
    private final int INFINITY = 1000000;
    private Vertex vertexList[]; // list of vertices
    private double adjMat[][]; // adjacency matrix
    private int nVerts; // current number of vertices
    private int nTree; //number of verts in tree
    private DistPar sPath[]; //array for shortest-path data
    private int currentVert;
    private PriorityQ thePQ;
    private double startToCurrent; //distance to currentVert
// -------------------------------------------------------------

    public Graph() // constructor
    {
        vertexList = new Vertex[MAX_VERTS];
        // adjacency matrix
        adjMat = new double[MAX_VERTS][MAX_VERTS];
        nVerts = 0;
        nTree=0;
        for(int j=0; j<MAX_VERTS; j++) // set adjacency
        for(int k=0; k<MAX_VERTS; k++) // matrix to 0
        adjMat[j][k] = INFINITY;
        thePQ = new PriorityQ();
        sPath = new DistPar[MAX_VERTS]; // shortest paths
    } // end constructor
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addVertex(int lab)
    {
        vertexList[nVerts++] = new Vertex(lab);
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addEdge(int start, int end, double weight)
    {
        adjMat[start][end] = weight;
        adjMat[end][start] = weight;
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void displayVertex(int v)
    {
        System.out.print(vertexList[v].label);
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    public void mstw() // minimum spanning tree
    {
        currentVert = 0; // start at 0
        while(nTree < nVerts-1) // while not all verts in tree
        { // put currentVert in tree
            vertexList[currentVert].isInTree = true;
            nTree++;
            // insert edges adjacent to currentVert into PQ
            for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++) // for each vertex,
            {
                if(j==currentVert) // skip if it’s us
                    continue;
                if(vertexList[j].isInTree) // skip if in the tree
                    continue;
                double distance = adjMat[currentVert][j];
                if( distance == INFINITY) // skip if no edge
                    continue;
                putInPQ(j, distance); // put it in PQ (maybe)
            }

            if(thePQ.size()==0) // no vertices in PQ?
            {
                System.out.println(" GRAPH NOT CONNECTED");
                return;
            }
            // remove edge with minimum distance, from PQ
            Edge theEdge = thePQ.removeMin();
            int sourceVert = theEdge.srcVert;
            currentVert = theEdge.destVert;
            // display edge from source to current
            System.out.print( vertexList[sourceVert].label );
            System.out.print( vertexList[currentVert].label );
            System.out.print(" ");
        } // end while(not all verts in tree)
        // mst is complete
        for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++) // unmark vertices
            vertexList[j].isInTree = false;
    } // end mstw
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void putInPQ(int newVert, double newDist)
    {
        // is there another edge with the same destination vertex?
        int queueIndex = thePQ.find(newVert);
        if(queueIndex != -1) // got edge’s index
        {
            Edge tempEdge = thePQ.peekN(queueIndex); // get edge
            double oldDist = tempEdge.distance;
            if(oldDist > newDist) // if new edge shorter,
            {
                thePQ.removeN(queueIndex); // remove old edge
                Edge theEdge = new Edge(currentVert, newVert, newDist);
                thePQ.insert(theEdge); // insert new edge
            }
            // else no action; just leave the old vertex there
        } // end if
        else // no edge with same destination vertex
        { // so insert new one
            Edge theEdge = new Edge(currentVert, newVert, newDist);
            thePQ.insert(theEdge);
        }
    } // end putInPQ()
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void path() // find all shortest paths
    {
        int startTree = 0; // start at vertex 0
        vertexList[startTree].isInTree = true;
        nTree = 1; // put it in tree
        // transfer row of distances from adjMat to sPath
        for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++)
        {
            double tempDist = adjMat[startTree][j];
            sPath[j] = new DistPar(startTree, tempDist);
        }
        // until all vertices are in the tree
        while(nTree < nVerts)
        {
            int indexMin = getMin(); // get minimum from sPath
            double minDist = sPath[indexMin].distance;
            if(minDist == INFINITY) // if all infinite
            { // or in tree,
                System.out.println("There are unreachable vertices");
                break; // sPath is complete
            }
            else
            { // reset currentVert
                currentVert = indexMin; // to closest vert
                startToCurrent = sPath[indexMin].distance;
                // minimum distance from startTree is
                // to currentVert, and is startToCurrent
            }
            // put current vertex in tree
            vertexList[currentVert].isInTree = true;
            nTree++;
            adjust_sPath(); // update sPath[] array
        } // end while(nTree<nVerts)
        displayPaths(); // display sPath[] contents
        nTree = 0; // clear tree
        for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++)
            vertexList[j].isInTree = false;
    } // end path()

    public int getMin() // get entry from sPath
    { // with minimum distance
        double minDist = INFINITY; // assume large minimum
        int indexMin = 0;
        for(int j=1; j<nVerts; j++) // for each vertex,
        { // if it’s in tree and
            if( !vertexList[j].isInTree && // smaller than old one
            sPath[j].distance < minDist )
            {
                minDist = sPath[j].distance;
                indexMin = j; // update minimum
            }
        } // end for
        return indexMin; // return index of minimum
    } // end getMin()

    public void adjust_sPath()
    {
        // adjust values in shortest-path array sPath
        int column = 1; // skip starting vertex
        while(column < nVerts) // go across columns
        {
            // if this column’s vertex already in tree, skip it
            if( vertexList[column].isInTree )
            {
                column++;
                continue;
            }
            // calculate distance for one sPath entry
            // get edge from currentVert to column
            double currentToFringe = adjMat[currentVert][column];
            // add distance from start
            double startToFringe = startToCurrent + currentToFringe;
            // get distance of current sPath entry
            double sPathDist = sPath[column].distance;
            // compare distance from start with sPath entry
            if(startToFringe < sPathDist) // if shorter,
            { // update sPath
                sPath[column].parentVert = currentVert;
                sPath[column].distance = startToFringe;
            }
            column++;
        } // end while(column < nVerts)
    } // end adjust_sPath()

    public void displayPaths()
    {
        for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++) // display contents of sPath[]
        {
            System.out.print(vertexList[j].label + "="); // B=
            if(sPath[j].distance == INFINITY)
                System.out.print("inf"); // inf
            else
                System.out.print(sPath[j].distance); // 50
                int parent = vertexList[ sPath[j].parentVert ].label;
                System.out.print("(" + parent + ") "); // (A)
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
 } // end class Graph
```

All the other classes involved just hold constructors and there's a priority queue class to try and implement the algorithm in a different way but I'm still getting the same null pointer. All suggestions welcome, even if I have to completely change my code!! :)

Comment: You should consider creating [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are high chances that you will find cause of your problems while creating it and you will also make helping you easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `Latitude` (and `Longitude`)

```
double[] Latitude = new double[size];
```

should be

```
Latitude = new double[size];
```

Note: Java naming conventions suggest that variables start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `latitude` and `longitude`